# how to use factory method for this collection in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, collection

`$object` method is working for me but i want to convert this collection in `factory method`.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Group\Collection');
```

Comment: What about using DI to inject the method directly in your constructor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try with below method,
There are many core files for frontend and backend module they used **Group\CollectionFactory** method you can get direction from that file.

You can refer **frontend** core file from here,

```
magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Config.php
```

**If you want to modify into backend, you can look at below core files,**

```
magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Attribute/Save.php
```

Inside your php file,

```
protected $_groupCollectionFactory;
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Group\CollectionFactory $groupCollectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->_groupCollectionFactory = $groupCollectionFactory;
    }
public function getGroupCollection()
   {
        return $this->_groupCollectionFactory->create()->load();
   }
```